# Python - Adding new Sub Element with Attribute

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I need a help on my python script. 
I've created a script where we can add a new bank holiday to the XML file.
It's working fine (probably I didn't do in the best way, as I'm still learning...), but **I had to a new Root to the XML**, and now I'm stuck, as it's not working.

This is the ***initial XML***:

```
<Holidays>
    <ISR_01>
        <DATE_ISR_01 D="03030303">Off</DATE_ISR_01>
        <DATE_ISR_01 D="05050505">Off</DATE_ISR_01>
    </ISR_01>
    <ISR_02>
        <DATE_ISR_02 D="04040404">Off</DATE_ISR_02>
        <DATE_ISR_02 D="01010101">Off</DATE_ISR_02>
    </ISR_02>
    <ISR_03>
        <DATE_ISR_03 D="01010101">Off</DATE_ISR_03>
    </ISR_03>
</Holidays>
```

And this is my code, which is working:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('Bank_Holidays.xml')
root = doc.getroot()
ISR_TEAM = 'ISR_01'
DATE_ISR_TEAM = ('DATE_' + ISR_TEAM)
XPath_Date = ('count(//' + DATE_ISR_TEAM + ')')
count = doc.xpath(XPath_Date)
result = len(root.getchildren())
filtro = "*"
for child in root.iter(filtro):
    pass
NEW_BANK_HOLIDAY = '32122020'       ####### NEW BANK HOLIDAY TO BE ADDED
tree = ET.parse('Bank_Holidays.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

tree = ET.parse('Bank_Holidays.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
element = child.tag
attrib = {}
attrib = {'D': NEW_BANK_HOLIDAY}
subelement = root[0][int(count - 1)].makeelement(DATE_ISR_TEAM, attrib)
ET.SubElement(root[0], DATE_ISR_TEAM, attrib)
root[0][int(count)].text = 'Off'
tree.write('Bank_Holidays.xml')
```

**But now**, I needed to change the XML file to this format, and I don't know how to keep doing this job.
The idea is the same: adding a new bank holiday line (`<DATE_ISR_01 D="05050505">Off</DATE_ISR_01>`) to this xml:

```
<UCCX>
    <Holidays>
        <ISR_01>
            <DATE_ISR_01 D="03030303">Off</DATE_ISR_01>
            <DATE_ISR_01 D="05050505">Off</DATE_ISR_01>
        </ISR_01>
        <ISR_02>
            <DATE_ISR_02 D="04040404">Off</DATE_ISR_02>
            <DATE_ISR_02 D="01010101">Off</DATE_ISR_02>
        </ISR_02>
        <ISR_03>
            <DATE_ISR_03 D="01010101">Off</DATE_ISR_03>
        </ISR_03>
    </Holidays>
</UCCX>
```

**How can I achieve the same result, with this new XML ??**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This method is not necessarily useful for you, it is only for reference.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils

html = '''
<Holidays>
    <ISR_01>
        <DATE_ISR_01 D="03030303">Off</DATE_ISR_01>
        <DATE_ISR_01 D="05050505">Off</DATE_ISR_01>
    </ISR_01>
    <ISR_02>
        <DATE_ISR_02 D="04040404">Off</DATE_ISR_02>
        <DATE_ISR_02 D="01010101">Off</DATE_ISR_02>
    </ISR_02>
    <ISR_03>
        <DATE_ISR_03 D="01010101">Off</DATE_ISR_03>
    </ISR_03>
</Holidays>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
Holidays = doc.select('Holidays')
Holidays.insertBefore("<UCCX>\n")
Holidays.insertAfter("\n</UCCX>")
print (doc.html)
```

Comment: Are you the author of https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy?

Comment: No, but I know him.